# C# StreamReader omit carriage return and new line but not in all machines

Tags: c#, text, streamreader

I have a text file, let's call it "dummyTextFile.txt". The file contains 2 lines of strings;

> This is the first line.
> This is the second line.

I use StreamReader to read the file in the following manner:-

```
var reader = new StreamReader("dummyTextFile.txt");
var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now, I have a unit test that do assert the that the read file is compared to the string of `"This is the first line.\r\nThis is the second line"` is equal in value. However, while some machines in our pool passed this test successfully, some doesn't. When I checked into the log, the StreamReader.ReadToEnd() is actually giving me `This is the first line.This is the second line.' as one line string instead of 2 line string.

Why is this so? Why do some machines that runs the unit test omit the return carriage and new line character? Mind you that the machines in the pool are located from all over the world so there might be some regional settings differences that I'm not aware of but I don't think it should impact how the carriage return and new line is being handled by the StreamReader?

Additional note: Code is running on .Net Framework 4.6.2, all machines in the pool are running Windows 10, possibly various build/update.

Comment: What operating System are you using?  Microsoft developed latest version of Core so Net library would run on Linux machine.  Then Microsoft modified Notepad to work with Linux returns.  So now notepad isn't working with legacy windows files (not seeing returns).  I was told last week on this website that ReadLine() works with any return.   I didn't believe it was true.  You are first to prove I'm right.

Comment: It's Windows 10, .Net Framework 4.6.2 and it should be the same across the machines in the pool. Unless that 'linux return' change doesn't happen on all Windows 10 build, that might not be the cause? I hope that's not the cause.

Comment: @jdweng, given that the OP is calling `ReadToEnd`, I'm not sure how that proves anything about `ReadLine`.

Comment: @jdweng, also I just wrote `"First line\rSecond line\nThird line\r\nFourth line"` to a file on Windows 11 using .NET 6 and, when I read the file back using `StreamReader.ReadLine` in a loop, I got the expected four lines. It seems that `ReadLine` works as advertised. I was under the impression that it had been that way for quite a long time. I ran the same code under .NET Framework 6.6.2 and got the same result.

Comment: I would suggest calling `File.ReadAllText` rather than creating a `StreamReader` and calling `ReadToEnd`. I've not looked but I suspect that the former does the latter internally, but it makes your code a bit more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code on Windows 11 under .NET Framework 4.6.2:

```cs
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
var text = "First line\rSecond line\nThird line\r\nFourth line";

Console.WriteLine("text.Length: {0}", text.Length);
Console.WriteLine();

File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);

var lines = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        lines.Add(line);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, lines[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    var output1 = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(output1);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("output1.Length: {0}", output1.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("output1 == text: {0}", output1 == text);
}

Console.WriteLine();

var output2 = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

Console.WriteLine(output2);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("output2.Length: {0}", output2.Length);
Console.WriteLine("output2 == text: {0}", output2 == text);

File.Delete(filePath);

Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the output I saw:

```
text.Length: 46

0: First line
1: Second line
2: Third line
3: Fourth line

Second line
Third line
Fourth line

output1.Length: 46
output1 == text: True

Second line
Third line
Fourth line

output2.Length: 46
output2 == text: True
```

That output seems a little weird so I used the debugger to check and `output1` and `output2` did indeed look the same as `text`. I guess the lone carriage return causes the console caret to go back to the start of the line without advancing, so the second line is overwriting the first.

Despite that, this shows that `System.IO` types can handle all three of those possible line breaks. I suggest that you do some manual testing on those machines with code like this to see if they all behave the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the experiment and suggestion. Manual testing on those machines is not exactly ideal as I don't have access to all of them, testing through pipeline will disrupt other's PR. So, I'm guessing either I'm going to have to mock this to make it deterministic or exclude the code from coverage report and rely on our system testing for that hole.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in my system. Was able to solve it by using

```
videoUrl = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList<string>();
```

this one didn't seems to have the issue of skipping newline characters.